# Conditionally Render Child Component within Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component `DataTable` that has `Column` child components. I want to include a specific `Column` child component if a prop is set to true. I've tried logical && and the ternary operator. The problem is that I can't pass any null or undefined value to `DataTable`. Logical && and the ternary operator seem to be providing a false, null, or undefined value as a child to `DataTable` when `this.props.hasMiddleName` is false. How can I fix this code so I do not pass any falsy values when `this.props.hasMiddleName` is false?

```
<DataTable dataUrl={this.props.url}>
    <Column Header={"First Name"} />
    { this.props.hasMiddleName &&
       <Column Header={"Middle Name"} />
    }
    <Column Header={"Last Name"} />
</DataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an array of children in another function.

```
renderChildren = () => {
    let children = [<Column Header={"First Name"} />]
    if(this.props.hasMiddleName) {
        children.push(<Column Header={"Middle Name"} />)
    }
    children.push(<Column Header={"Last Name"} />)
    return children
}
```

And inside `DataTable` you call the function wich will render it's children.

```
<DataTable dataUrl={this.props.url}>
    {this.renderChildren()}
</DataTable>
```